# Spring Filter ClassCastException when running project on Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, websphere, spring-web

I am getting following error when I try to run my project on WebSphere 8.5.I used scope provided and exclusion thing but its not working.Seems servlet-api.jar is being taken from Web Container.The Spring-web version I am using is 3.0.5

```
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [filterChainProxy]: not a filter class
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: HealthCheckServlet
Error Stack: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy incompatible with javax.servlet.Filter 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:572) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:514) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:319)
```

Comment: try changing the classloading policy to PARENT_LAST

Comment: remove servlet-api jar from web-inf/lib

Comment: @Gas You should just make that an answer.